# python unique list based on item

Tags: python, list, unique

I have a list

```
old_list = [
        (1, 'AAA', None, 1),
        (2, 'AAA', 'x', 0),
        (5, 'AAB', 'z', 1),
        (6, 'ABB', 'x', 1),
        (9, 'ABB', 'x', 1)]
```

How I want get a new list have unique i[1] and the bigger id i[0], like this result

```
new_list = [
        (2, 'AAA', 'x', 0),
        (5, 'AAB', 'z', 1),
        (9, 'ABB', 'x', 1)]
]
```

can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
old_list = [
        (1, 'AAA', None, 1),
        (2, 'AAA', 'x', 0),
        (5, 'AAB', 'z', 1),
        (6, 'ABB', 'x', 1),
        (9, 'ABB', 'x', 1)]
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
print [sorted(list(group), key=itemgetter(0))[-1]
       for key, group in groupby(old_list, key=itemgetter(1))]
```

**Output**

```
[(2, 'AAA', 'x', 0), (5, 'AAB', 'z', 1), (9, 'ABB', 'x', 1)]
```

if the `old_list` is not sorted already, you can sort it like this

```
old_list = sorted([
        (1, 'AAA', None, 1),
        (2, 'AAA', 'x', 0),
        (5, 'AAB', 'z', 1),
        (6, 'ABB', 'x', 1),
        (9, 'ABB', 'x', 1)], key=itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: (No Down-voting). Prefer `operator.itemgetter` over lambda. You also do not need the sort of individual groups. Just pick the last item in the list. If the items are not actually sorted, sort them by second element followed by first before applying groupby.

Comment: @Abhijit Oh. Thanks for the suggestion. But, is there any specific reasons to do so?

Comment: 1. If something is available in the library prefer it over rolling one. 2. If you see how python is evolving, there is a general consensus to move away from using `lambda`.

Comment: Thanks @Abhijit. I updated it. BTW, what is the alternate for `lambda` in the future?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
d={}
for t in old_list:
    d.setdefault(t[1],[]).append(t)
    
new_list=[]    
for k in sorted(d):       # sort by the keys ('AAA', 'AAB', etc)
    new_list.append(max(d[k], key=lambda t: t[0]))    # max index (t[0])
# [(2, 'AAA', 'x', 0), (5, 'AAB', 'z', 1), (9, 'ABB', 'x', 1)]
```

---

Edit

If there are no possibilities of duplicate ID's, you can do:

```
d={}
for t in old_list:
    d.setdefault(t[1],[]).append(t)
    
new_list=[]    
for k in sorted(d):
    new_list.append(d[k][-1])
```

Which is the same answer with the sample data.

---

### Edit 2, Timings

```
from collections import defaultdict

s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]

def f1():
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in s:
        d[k].append(v)
        
    return d.items()
    
def f2():
    d={}
    for k, v in s:
        d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
        
    return d.items()            
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    import sys
    print(sys.version)
    print('defaultdict:', timeit.timeit("f1()", setup="from __main__ import f1, s"))
    print('setdefault:', timeit.timeit("f2()", setup="from __main__ import f2, s"))
```

Prints:

```
3.3.2 (default, Jul  6 2013, 10:40:18) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)]
defaultdict: 2.384568103996571
setdefault: 1.6183147379779257
```

And timings with post shows that this is a massively faster way to do this:

```
from __future__ import print_function 
from collections import OrderedDict
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter

old_list = [
        (1, 'AAA', None, 1),
        (2, 'AAA', 'x', 0),
        (5, 'AAB', 'z', 1),
        (6, 'ABB', 'x', 1),
        (9, 'ABB', 'x', 1)]
        
def f1():
    d={}
    for t in old_list:
        d.setdefault(t[1],[]).append(t)

    new_list=[]    
    for k in sorted(d):
        new_list.append(d[k][-1]) 
    
    return new_list    
            
def f2():
    nl = sorted(old_list, key=itemgetter(2,1))
    return OrderedDict((elem[1], elem) 
             for elem in nl).values()    
            
def f3():
    nl=sorted(old_list, key=lambda x: x[1])
    return [sorted(list(group), key=lambda x:x[0], reverse=True)[0]
               for key, group in itertools.groupby(nl, key=lambda x:x[1])]                  
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    import sys
    print(sys.version) 
    print('drewk:',timeit.timeit("f1()", setup="from __main__ import f1, old_list"))
    print('Abhijit:', timeit.timeit("f2()", setup="from __main__ import f2, old_list, OrderedDict, itemgetter"))
    print('thefourtheye:', timeit.timeit("f3()", setup="from __main__ import f3, old_list, itertools"))
```

Prints:

```
2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)]
drewk: 3.30526208878
Abhijit: 20.5611379147
thefourtheye: 13.2195081711
```

Comment: I believe you overlooked the fact that the latest element inserted in the dictionary persist. So you do not need the post processing of traversing the list and finding the max. Also, `defaultdict` is preferred over `setdefault`. Finally, not using `OrderedDict`, you have discarded an already sorted data. So overall a bad approach.

Comment: @Abhijit: A) Where is it stated that `defaultdict` is 'preferred' over `setdefault`; B) The OP stated 'I want ... the bigger id i[0]' He does NOT state that this is ordered by ID or there are not duplicates; C) `OrderedDict` is written in Python. Sorting by the keys of t[1] is very probably faster than keeping a Python vs C dict. Certainly a C dict is way faster than OrderedDict

Comment: `Where is it stated that defaultdict is 'preferred' over setdefault`. Read the [docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/defaultdict-examples.html). `Sorting by the keys of t[1] is very probably faster than keeping a Python vs C dict` Multiple sorting of smaller sublist cannot be faster than OrderedDict

Comment: @Abhijit: Please see timings. Using the example on that linked page, `defaultdict` is not faster nor is it easier than `setdefault`

Comment: Your timings are flawed; with such a small dataset, the creation time of the object plays a disproportionally large role. Using a literal `{}` is far faster than invoking a factory function (`defaultdict()`).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Please clarify: All the timings are bad or only the one of `setdefault` vs `defaultdict`? Granted, the sample size is small. If I multiply the the list *10 and *100 then `defaultdict` has an advantage. I do not claim that `setdefault` is better, but neither is it true that defaultdict is 'preferred'

Comment: However: If I multiply the OP's data structure *10 and *100, the relative speed / slowness of the three methods is relatively unchanged. Everyone has the timing code: Try It!

Comment: This was in response to someone now wanting to know why `defaultdict` exists at all as it is slower, quoting your post. Of course timings vary by exact problem domain and you should always conduct your own timings, but be sure to make that disclaimer clear. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I am confused. Who wanted to know why `defaultdict` exists at all? Not me. Both are great in the appropriate use. [Horses for courses](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Horses+for+courses) Cheers!

Comment: @drewk: I quite agree. See [OrderedDict vs defaultdict vs dict](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19629682) for the flawed assumptions.