# OrderedDict vs defaultdict vs dict

Tags: python, dictionary

In python's library, we now have two Python Implementation of dictionaries which subclasses `dict` over and above the native `dict` type.

Python's  advocates have always preferred to `defaultdict` over using `dict.setdefault` where possible. Even the [doc](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/defaultdict-examples.html) quotes that `This technique is simpler and faster than an equivalent technique using dict.setdefault():`

In similar ways, as dictionaries does not maintain order, using `OrderedDict` over using `dict` followed by  sorting the items is preferred when ever possible for the alternative usage.

In both the above case, the code is definitely cleaner but at the cost of performance penalty.

While answering and commenting on one of the question [python unique list based on item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626749/python-unique-list-based-on-item/19626840?noredirect=1#comment29138676_19626840), I stumbled upon the performance penalty over the native `dict` when using `defaultdict` and `OrderedDict`. It also seems the size of the data is also not immaterial to the performance advantage `dict` solution has over others.

I believe `There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.`, so what is the preferred way?

Comment: `defaultdict` is not necessarily slower than a regular `dict`. The timings there are flawed, as the timings *include creating the object*. Other than that, there are different types of performance, maintenance ease being one. You didn't specify any criteria by which to measure performance. Just use the **right tool for the job**.

Comment: Just to reiterate again: do your *own* timings for your usecases. The timings you cite are for a small dataset and include creation of the dictionary objects; because a dict literal (`{}`) is *far* faster to create than a `defaultdict(...)` factory call (global lookup, stack push, invocation) that skews the results unfairly on small datasets. The presumption that `defaultdict` is slower is flawed.

Comment: While I agree that a `defaultdict` is frequently preferable to having to call `dict.setdefault`, why would `OrderedDict` be "preferred whenever possible" to a `dict`? I don't think I've ever cared about the order in which keys were inserted into a dictionary, and that's a far more specific feature than simply providing a default value for a new key.

Answer (score 72):

There is not one single answer and not one true and only dict. Among many variables, it depends on:

1. Size of the data set;
2. Number of unique keys vs the number of duplicate keys in the set of data mappings;
3. Speed of the underlying factory for defaultdict;
4. Speed of OrderDict vs some later ordering step;
5. Version of Python.

I am *loathe* to generalize, but here are some generalities:

1. The statement `This technique is simpler and faster than an equivalent technique using dict.setdefault()` is just flat wrong. It depends on the data;
2. `setdefault` is faster and simpler with small data sets;
3. `defaultdict` is faster for larger data sets with more homogenous key sets (ie, how short the dict is after adding elements);
4. `setdefault` has an advantage with more heterogeneous key sets;
5. these results are different for Python 3 vs Python 2;
6. `OrderedDict` is slower in all cases other than an algorithm that depends on order and order is not easy to reconstruct or sort;
7. Python 3 is generally faster for most `dict` operations;
8. Python 3.6's dict is now ordered by insertion order (reducing the usefulness of `OrderedDict`).

The only truth: **It Depends!** All three technique are useful.

Here is some timing code to show:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import OrderedDict

try:
    t=unichr(100)
except NameError:
    unichr=chr

def f1(li):
    '''defaultdict'''
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in li:
        d[k].append(v)
    return d.items()

def f2(li):
    '''setdefault'''
    d={}
    for k, v in li:
        d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
    return d.items()

def f3(li):
    '''OrderedDict'''
    d=OrderedDict()
    for k, v in li:
        d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
    return d.items()      


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    import sys
    print(sys.version)
    few=[('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]
    fmt='{:>12}: {:10.2f} micro sec/call ({:,} elements, {:,} keys)'
    for tag, m, n in [('small',5,10000), ('medium',20,1000), ('bigger',1000,100), ('large',5000,10)]:
        for f in [f1,f2,f3]:
            s = few*m
            res=timeit.timeit("{}(s)".format(f.__name__), setup="from __main__ import {}, s".format(f.__name__), number=n)
            st=fmt.format(f.__doc__, res/n*1000000, len(s), len(f(s)))
            print(st)
            s = [(unichr(i%0x10000),i) for i in range(1,len(s)+1)]
            res=timeit.timeit("{}(s)".format(f.__name__), setup="from __main__ import {}, s".format(f.__name__), number=n)
            st=fmt.format(f.__doc__, res/n*1000000, len(s), len(f(s)))
            print(st)            
        print()
```

Python 2.7 result:

```
2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)]
 defaultdict:      10.20 micro sec/call (25 elements, 3 keys)
 defaultdict:      21.08 micro sec/call (25 elements, 25 keys)
  setdefault:      13.41 micro sec/call (25 elements, 3 keys)
  setdefault:      18.24 micro sec/call (25 elements, 25 keys)
 OrderedDict:      49.47 micro sec/call (25 elements, 3 keys)
 OrderedDict:     102.16 micro sec/call (25 elements, 25 keys)

 defaultdict:      28.28 micro sec/call (100 elements, 3 keys)
 defaultdict:      79.78 micro sec/call (100 elements, 100 keys)
  setdefault:      45.68 micro sec/call (100 elements, 3 keys)
  setdefault:      68.66 micro sec/call (100 elements, 100 keys)
 OrderedDict:     117.78 micro sec/call (100 elements, 3 keys)
 OrderedDict:     343.17 micro sec/call (100 elements, 100 keys)

 defaultdict:    1123.60 micro sec/call (5,000 elements, 3 keys)
 defaultdict:    4250.44 micro sec/call (5,000 elements, 5,000 keys)
  setdefault:    2089.86 micro sec/call (5,000 elements, 3 keys)
  setdefault:    3803.03 micro sec/call (5,000 elements, 5,000 keys)
 OrderedDict:    4399.16 micro sec/call (5,000 elements, 3 keys)
 OrderedDict:   16279.14 micro sec/call (5,000 elements, 5,000 keys)

 defaultdict:    5609.39 micro sec/call (25,000 elements, 3 keys)
 defaultdict:   25351.60 micro sec/call (25,000 elements, 25,000 keys)
  setdefault:   10267.00 micro sec/call (25,000 elements, 3 keys)
  setdefault:   24091.51 micro sec/call (25,000 elements, 25,000 keys)
 OrderedDict:   22091.98 micro sec/call (25,000 elements, 3 keys)
 OrderedDict:   94028.00 micro sec/call (25,000 elements, 25,000 keys)
```

Python 3.3 result:

```
3.3.2 (default, May 21 2013, 11:50:47) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))]
 defaultdict:       8.58 micro sec/call (25 elements, 3 keys)
 defaultdict:      21.18 micro sec/call (25 elements, 25 keys)
  setdefault:      10.42 micro sec/call (25 elements, 3 keys)
  setdefault:      14.58 micro sec/call (25 elements, 25 keys)
 OrderedDict:      45.43 micro sec/call (25 elements, 3 keys)
 OrderedDict:      92.69 micro sec/call (25 elements, 25 keys)

 defaultdict:      20.47 micro sec/call (100 elements, 3 keys)
 defaultdict:      77.48 micro sec/call (100 elements, 100 keys)
  setdefault:      34.22 micro sec/call (100 elements, 3 keys)
  setdefault:      54.86 micro sec/call (100 elements, 100 keys)
 OrderedDict:     107.37 micro sec/call (100 elements, 3 keys)
 OrderedDict:     318.98 micro sec/call (100 elements, 100 keys)

 defaultdict:     714.70 micro sec/call (5,000 elements, 3 keys)
 defaultdict:    3892.92 micro sec/call (5,000 elements, 5,000 keys)
  setdefault:    1502.91 micro sec/call (5,000 elements, 3 keys)
  setdefault:    2888.08 micro sec/call (5,000 elements, 5,000 keys)
 OrderedDict:    3912.95 micro sec/call (5,000 elements, 3 keys)
 OrderedDict:   14863.02 micro sec/call (5,000 elements, 5,000 keys)

 defaultdict:    3649.02 micro sec/call (25,000 elements, 3 keys)
 defaultdict:   22313.17 micro sec/call (25,000 elements, 25,000 keys)
  setdefault:    7447.28 micro sec/call (25,000 elements, 3 keys)
  setdefault:   18426.88 micro sec/call (25,000 elements, 25,000 keys)
 OrderedDict:   19202.17 micro sec/call (25,000 elements, 3 keys)
 OrderedDict:   85946.45 micro sec/call (25,000 elements, 25,000 keys)
```

Comment: "`defaultdict` is faster for ... more homogenous key sets". What did you mean by "homogenous" here? Are you referring to homogeneity of type?

Comment: The 'homogeneity' refers to how many keys after adding some number of elements that may have duplicates. If you do `dict(zip('123','abc'))` you end up with 3 keys from 3 adds - 0 homogeneity; if you do `dict(zip('111','abc'))` you end up with a dict with 1 key from three additions - very homogenous.

Comment: @dawg I *suspect* that if you use `list()` instead of `[]` in `setdefault` the differences would practically disappear among the many-key versions. This might be relevant if you cannot use a literal in `.setdefault`, e.g. with `set` objects

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I added that to the benchmark and yes, they are a bit closer but not dramatically so...

Answer (score 10):

I feel that your assumption - *only one preferable way* - does not hold. I see **at least two** cases with different requirements:

> In **maintenance-intensive** code (e.g. an option parser of an evolving utility class) I would always go for **cleaner code**, so that others and I can implement new features more easily. The performance is not critical, as only small quantities (e.g. a dict of user settings) are processed.

while in

> the implementation of a **performance-critical** algorithm in a data processing task, I would not mind writing a bit **more verbose code for much faster execution**. If the alorithm is unlikely to change, the little less readable code won't become an issue.

Comment: `the implementation of a performance-critical algorithm in a data processing task, I would not mind writing a bit more verbose code for much faster execution`? In such scenario, why would one not write the implementation in native code? `only one preferable way` .. thats not my assumption but the guidelines from Tim Peters.

Comment: For a given, fully specified use case (and fully known boundary conditions), it *might* be possible to settle for *one* preferable way. But I would argue those cases are rare. Most of the time, some trade off (performance, readability, generality, ...) has to be made and the preferable way is basically a subjective selection of the option with the least *perceived* disadvantages.

Comment: Some of it is just ROI. Complexity of writing it in, say, Cython, or going to PyPy is higher than stock python, and compiling a C library is more complex still. You can decide that the tradeoffs for going partway (a faster native python solution) is worth it, while the tradeoffs for going farther (a native library) aren't.