# Reading data from large text file with strings and floats in Python

Tags: python, file, sorting, split

I'm having trouble reading large amounts of data from a text file, and splitting and removing certain objects from it to get a more refined list. For example, let's say I have a text file, we'll call it 'data.txt', that has this data in it.

```
Some Header Here
Object Number = 1
Object Symbol = A
Mass of Object = 1
Weight of Object = 1.2040
Hight of Object = 0.394
Width of Object = 4.2304

Object Number = 2
Object Symbol = B
Mass Number = 2
Weight of Object = 1.596
Height of Object = 3.293
Width of Object = 4.654
.
.
. ...Same format continuing down
```

My problem is taking the data I need from this file. Let's say I'm only interested in the Object Number and Mass of Object, which repeats through the file, but with different numerical values. I need a list of this data. Example

```
Object Number    Mass of Object
1                1
2                2
.                .
.                .
.                .
etc.
```

With the headers excluded of course, as this data will be applied to an equation. I'm very new to Python, and don't have any knowledge of OOP. What would be the easiest way to do this? I know the basics of opening and writing to text files, even a little bit of using the split and strip functions. I've researched quite a bit on this site about sorting data, but I can't get it to work for me.

Comment: Have you tried any code? if so, let's see it and start there.

Comment: I've gone through a bunch of different codes that didn't work, which I didn't save. I coded up something really simple to demonstrate.import sys

f = open('data.txt', 'r')

A = f.readlines()

for i in A:
    B = i.split("=")
    if i in B == 'Object Number':
        print B.remove('Object Number')   Of course this didn't work, I don't get output. If i remove the if statement, I do get output, and it does split by the = sign, but for some reason its jumping in the text file and starting at Object Number = 120, and not the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
object_number = [] # list of Object Number
mass_of_object = [] # list of Mass of Object
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('Object Number'):
            object_number.append(int(line.split('=')[1]))
        elif line.startswith('Mass of Object'):
            mass_of_object.append(int(line.split('=')[1]))
```

Comment: This code works for me, and I understand it more so than what Alessandro posted (no fault on his part, I'm just extremely new to python). I added some more code to write this to a separate file. {f2 = open('data2.txt', 'w'); for item in object_number:
  f2.write("%s\n" % item) } this works, and I get the first column of data for the object number. How would I go about writing more code to append the mass of object in a second column? Thanks for your help, I'll play around with this more and see what I come up with.

Comment: @Collaptic, if my answer help you please [Accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, thanks. i edit my code and read file line by line.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion dictionary (and sub-classes) has an efficiency greater than a group of lists for huge data input.

Moreover, my code don't need any modification if you need to extract a new object data from your file.

```
from _collections import defaultdict

checklist = ["Object Number", "Mass of Object"]
data = dict()

with open("text.txt") as f:
    # iterating over the file allows
    # you to read it automatically one line at a time
    for line in f:
        for regmatch in checklist:
            if line.startswith(regmatch):
                # this is to erase newline characters
                val = line.rstrip()
                val = val.split(" = ")[1]
                data.setdefault(regmatch, []).append(val)                    

print data
```

This is the output:

```
defaultdict(None, {'Object Number': ['1', '2'], 'Mass of Object': ['1']})
```

[Here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) some theory about speed, [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips) some tips about performance optimization and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629682/ordereddict-vs-defaultdict-vs-dict) about dependency between type of data and implementation efficiency.

Last, some examples about `re` (regular expression):

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Comment: This sorta worked. When I applied it to my data.txt file, it did spit out a list. But only a list of of the Object Numbers, and not the Mass of Object. I will have to play around with the code a bit more, but I'm unfamiliar with a lot of the things you coded, like the import re, _collections, defaultdict, reg_exp. I'll have to look into these and see if I can wrap my head around them. Thanks

Comment: Of course if you need to export more objects you can extend the list `checklist`. If my solution work for you can choose it ? :-)