# Converting a 1D list into a 2D DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have scraped a webpage table, and the table items are in a sequential 1D list, with repeated headers. I want to reconstitute the table into a DataFrame.

I have an algorithm to do this, *but I'd like to know if there is a more pythonic/efficient way to achieve this*? NB. I don't necessarily know how many columns there are in my table. Here's an example:

```
input = ['A',1,'B',5,'C',9,
         'A',2,'B',6,'C',10,
         'A',3,'B',7,'C',11,
         'A',4,'B',8,'C',12]

output = {}

it = iter(input)
val = next(it)

while val:
    if val in output:
        output[val].append(next(it))
    else:
        output[val] = [next(it)]

    val = next(it,None)

df = pd.DataFrame(output)

print(df)
```

with the result:

```
   A  B   C
0  1  5   9
1  2  6  10
2  3  7  11
3  4  8  12
```

Comment: Will this pattern always hold strictly?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Hard to say for sure: but that is my working assumption: An n x m array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is always "well behaved", then something like this should suffice:

```
import pandas as pd

data = ['A',1,'B',5,'C',9,
         'A',2,'B',6,'C',10,
         'A',3,'B',7,'C',11,
         'A',4,'B',8,'C',12]

result = {}

for k,v in zip(data[::2], data[1::2]):
    result.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

df = pd.DataFrame(output)
```

Comment: any reason to choose between `dict.setdefault` vs `d = defaultdict(list)`?

Comment: @LeiYang not really, there may be some cases where it is slightly faster, depends on the nature of the data... See [this interesting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19643045/5014455), however, it is a bit dated. In any case, probably clarity is a better consideration.

Comment: @LeiYang although, I generally hate keeping a `defaultdict` around as a default dict after I'm done creating it. Generally, I don't *want* `my_dict[key]` to automatically add a key if it doesn't exist, only in a very narrow circumstance. In which case, I can avoid that by using `setdefault`. But you can always just `dict(my_default_dict)` or even, `my_default_dict.default_factory = None`

Comment: Correcting 'output' to 'result' in the code, and it works a treat. Thanks!

Comment: Just thinking about this a little more. If there were a LOT of rows, would it be more efficient to set a flag when you find a repeat key in the dictionary for the first time (ie you have been through the columns once), and then not check again once the flag has been tripped, and just do the `append`? Presumably `setdefault` is doing the `in` check internally on every loop?

Comment: @DS_London No. You *always* effectively have to check if a key is `in` a dictionary, even when *adding or retrieving values*. It's a hash map.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use numpy reshape:

```
import numpy as np
cols = sorted(set(l[::2]))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(l, (int(len(l)/len(cols)/2), len(cols)*2)).T[1::2].T, columns=cols)

   A  B   C
0  1  5   9
1  2  6  10
2  3  7  11
3  4  8  12
```

Explaination:

```
# get columns
cols = sorted(set(l[::2]))

# reshape list into list of lists
shape = (int(len(l)/len(cols)/2), len(cols)*2)
np.reshape(l, shape)

# get only the values of the data
.T[1::2].T
# this transposes the data and slices every second step
```